# HTTP 403 during Azure OMS registration

Tags: azure

When attempting to connect the Monitoring Agent on my server to Azure OMS I get this message in the even log on the server:

> The service returned HTTP status code 403 in response to a query.  Please check with the service administrator for the health of the service. The query will be retried later.

- The URL that is given lists the correct workspace ID.
- I made sure I entered the correct workspace id and primary key
- Tried with newly generated keys
- Re-installed the agent Made sure the time on both systems matches

It seems the connectivity is working otherwise the agent installation wouldn’t have worked and I wouldn’t have gotten an 403.

Answer (score 1):

I had a case with the same error and it turned out that there was an HTTP traffic inspection in place. The easiest way is to use Fiddler and check the certificate returned from the OMS server.

Regards, Grega